# Why does StringReplace wrap StringExpression around result?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

The task is to separate a leading separator from subsequent text into a list.

Why does `StringReplace` wrap `StringExpression` around the intended list?

```
StringReplace[("--" ~~ rest__) :> {"--", rest}]["-- blah "]
```

> StringExpression[{"--", " blah "}]

Is there a way to prevent this (obviously can post-process but seems a workaround). Without the List in the replacement rule, it's fine:

```
StringReplace[("--" ~~ rest__) :> rest]["-- blah "]
```

> " blah "

Comment: Use `:> "—"<>rest` instead

Comment: @CarlWoll, check the first line of my question. Your method returns the input unprocessed, it doesn't separate it into a list.

Comment: StringRrplace only returns a String or StringExpression object.

Comment: @CarlWoll, I see. I thought it would be more flexible. And I can't use `StringCases` as an alternative b/c there's non-matching text to pass through. What's the best alternative: `Replace[StringExpression[x_] :> x]`?

Comment: What's the actual task you are trying to do? Perhaps StringSplit does what you want, e.g., `StringSplit["-- blah", "--" -> "--"]`?

Comment: I don't get why `StringCases` can't be used, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Kuba, yes `StringCases` could be used, with an additional catch-all rule like `s__ :> s` for non-matching strings. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @CarlWoll, `StringSplit["-- blah", "--" -> "--"]` seems to work fine. Was not aware of that option. If you want to post as an answer will accept.